# Birt : How to get second row from dataSetRow["value"]

Tags: birt

I got xml as my data Source, I create DataSet which gives me two records for example :

```
cur, value, year
EUR  1000   2011
USD  2000   2011
```

and in grid (2x2) I would like to show data as follows :

```
EUR 1000
USD 2000
```

instead of that I got :

```
EUR 1000
EUR 1000
```

I get my data dataSetRow["cur"] , dataSetRow["value"];

I don't want to use list or table. so how can i get the second row ??  can i use some kind of iterator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Table object, not a Grid object, to display your values. Try dragging and dropping your dataset from the Data Explorer view directly into the Report Design Layout pane - it should insert a table automatically. (You may want to adjust column sizes.)

Switch to the Preview pane (don't forget to remove the unwanted grid object) - you should see all the dataset values in your report.